# Android display multiple messages in a single notification

Tags: android

Currently, I receive notifications from a server. What happens is, if I get a notification, I dont see it for long time. When a new notification comes, I lose the previous one. I want a single notification with multiple messages something like this -

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is InboxStyle notification

```
Notification notif = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
 .setContentTitle("5 New mails from " + sender.toString())
 .setContentText(subject)
 .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
 .setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
 .setStyle(new Notification.InboxStyle()
     .addLine(str1)
     .addLine(str2)
     .setContentTitle("")
     .setSummaryText("+3 more"))
 .build();
```

[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.InboxStyle.html) is official document

check this example also - [Inbox Style Notification Like Whatsapp](http://www.androidgig.com/inbox-style-notification-like-whatsapp/)

Comment: Thank you :) But here you have .addLine for predetermined messages. How can I have this dynamically. Suppose I get 100 messages and should I have 100 addLine statements?

Comment: You need to maintain those in local database or preference, depends on your application.

Comment: and you can not have 100 add line as you can not have that much long notification, add just 5-6 lines and than use `summaryText`

Comment: Ok but you might have seen in whatsapp sometimes you get so much messages from whatsapp groups like it exceeds 100. In that case they use local db as you said?

Comment: I guess, its best way  to store those in database or preferences based on your requirement, but as you have more number i would sugggest database